# I am trying to fill color of bars in a graph (svg element) using column values from a csv file, not working

Tags: csv, svg, d3.js

```
             d3.csv("file.csv", function(data){
            var svg1 = d3.selectAll(".graph").selectAll(".svg1");
            svg1.selectAll("rect").attr("fill",function(d,i)
            {
             return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.column * 10) + ")";
            });
            });
```

HTML Code :

```
          <div class = "graph">
          <rect class="bar" id="01" height="187" width="60" y="262" x="355"></rect> 
          <rect class="bar" id="02" ........................ </rect>
          .
          .
          .
          </div>
```

So i am trying to include the attribute "fill" to all the rect elements using the values from the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the data to the selection:

```
var svg1 = d3.select(".graph").select("svg");
svg1.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .style("fill", function (d, i) {
        return "rgb(0, 0, " + d + ")";
    });
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZePc5/) to illustrate the point. I used a variable to mimic the CSV data, so you would need to substitute the `d` representing the value in the simple array for the `d.column` in your CSV.